# IIS FTP 8 Custom Authentication Authorization rules denied the access

Tags: c#, ftp, iis-8

I have create a custom authenticator for IIS FTP 8 using C#.  I have set the custom feature handlers correctly so that IIS uses my DLL, but when I try to login I always get:

```
Response:   331 Password required
Command:    PASS ********
Response:   530-User cannot log in, home directory inaccessible.
Response:    Win32 error:   No such interface supported 
Response:    Error details: Authorization rules denied the access.
Response:   530 End
```

I'm pretty sure I've ruled out folder permissions - it is as wide open as it can be.  So as I understand the message - its telling me I don't have any authorization rules.  But there doesn't seem to be a way to add one for a custom authenticator.  The UI in IIS Manager blanks out the normal settings capabilities so you can't add any there.

I tried the app cmd:

```
appcmd.exe set config "mysite" -section:system.ftpServer/security/authorization /+"[accessType='Allow',roles='administrators',permissions='Read, Write']" /commit:apphost
```

with variations on the role (guest, *, etc.) with no success.

I tried editing the site's entry in applicationHost.config, but I can't find any documentation on where to put it other than this "non-custom" example from the microsoft docs:

```
<location path="ftp.example.com">
  <system.ftpServer>
    <security>
      <authorization>
        <add accessType="Allow" roles="administrators" permissions="Read, Write" />
      </authorization>
```

When I add an authorization tag in the indicated position in my config, the FTP service won't restart.

So how the heck do you add an authorization rule when you are using a custom FTP authentication provider?

For the sake of completeness, here's the code for the provider class.  Note the output to the text file in the LogMessage method.  That is showing me that everything is working - it just can't get to the user's home folder because there is no authorization rule for it.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Web.FtpServer;

namespace MyCustomFtpExtension
{
    public class DatabaseAuthenticator : BaseProvider,
        IFtpAuthenticationProvider,
        IFtpRoleProvider, IFtpHomeDirectoryProvider, IFtpPostprocessProvider,
        IFtpLogProvider
    {
        private readonly string _logfile = Path.Combine(@"c:\test", "logs", "FtpExtension.log");
        public bool AuthenticateUser(string sessionId, string siteName, string userName, string userPassword,
            out string canonicalUserName)
        {
            canonicalUserName = userName;

            var result = DatabaseHelper.Authenticate(userName, userPassword);
            if (result)
            {
                LogMessage("Login Success: " + userName);  //this message appears
            }
            else
            {
                LogMessage("Login Failure: " + userName);
            }
            return result;
        }

        string IFtpHomeDirectoryProvider.GetUserHomeDirectoryData(
            string sessionId,
            string siteName,
            string userName)
        {
            LogMessage("In ftp home directory");  //this message never appears

            return @"c:\temp\test";
        }

        public FtpProcessStatus HandlePostprocess(FtpPostprocessParameters postProcessParameters)
        {

            LogMessage("Running Post Process");  //this message never appears
            return FtpProcessStatus.FtpProcessContinue;
        }

        public bool IsUserInRole(string sessionId, string siteName, string userName, string userRole)
        {
            return true; // I don't care about this - if they authenticate, that's all I need.
        }


        //to keep the sample short I took out the log provider - it was copy / paste from Microsoft's example

        //this is a quick and dirty output so I can see what's going on (which isn't much)
        private void LogMessage(string logEntry)
        {
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(_logfile, true))
            {
                // Retrieve the current date and time for the log entry.
                var dt = DateTime.Now;

                sw.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\tMESSAGE:{2}",
                    dt.ToShortDateString(),
                    dt.ToLongTimeString(),
                    logEntry);
                sw.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to run command to assign library fir home directory provider.

```
AppCmd set site "FTP Site Name" /+ftpServer.customFeatures.providers.[name='CustomFtpAuthDemo',enabled='true']
```